# Return an item's price from a list by matching its item number

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a spreadsheet with a list of the items I sell.

For each item (1 per row), I have the following columns:

1. `Item Code` in Column H
2. `Item` (name) in Column I
3. Price `Per Pack` in Column J

**Example Data:**

|  | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Item Code** | **Item** | **Per Pack** |
| **2** | C1 | Choco Chip Cookies | 100 |
| **3** | C2 | Jolly Cookies | 100 |
| **4** | C3 | Cookies and Cream | 100 |
| **5** | M1 | Choco Mallows | 85 |
| **6** | M2 | Filled Mallows | 180 |
| **7** | N1 | Pistachios | 110 |
| **8** | N4 | Cashews | 85 |
| **9** | N5 | Cornick | 25 |
| **10** | G1 | Gummy Worms | 25 |

In the same sheet, I am trying to create a formula in Column C that returns the price that matches the `Item Code` chosen from the dropdown in Column B (`Request`).

In Column D I enter the `Quantity` and in Column E I can calculate the `Total` once I have the price.

I succeeded using the IF function for item `"C1"` but it only works for one item: `=IF(B2="C1",100,)`

How do I return the `Price` for an item using the `Item Code` chosen in Column B?

**Example Results:**

|  | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Request** | **Price** | **Quantity** | **Total** |
| **2** | C1 | 100 | 1 | 100 |
| **3** | C1 | 100 | 2 | 200 |

**Spreadsheet Screenshot**
[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

- delete everything in **B** column and paste this into **B1** cell:

```
={"Price"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, H:J, 3, 0)))}
```

- delete everything in **E** column and paste this into **E1** cell:

```
={"Total"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C<>"", C2:C*D2:D, ))}
```